# How to apply a function that creates columns to dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I try do some data wrangling on a data frame in R but I could find out why my solution does not work.

```
auditlog <- data.frame(X_ID=c(1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
           EVENT=c('create', 'delete', 'update', 'update', 'delete', 'delete', 'create', 
                   'create', 'update'),
           UNIT=c('30xx', '30xx', '30xx', '30xx', '30xx', '30xx', '30xx', '30xx', '30xx'),
           CREATED=c('2015-12-01', '2015-12-01', '2015-12-02', '2015-12-04',
                     '2015-12-05', '2015-12-06', '2015-12-10', '2015-12-10',
                     '2015-12-10'),
           R1=c('xxxxxxxx11', 'title', 'xxxxxxxx25', 'xxxxxxxx11', 'new_title',
                '_title', 'xxxxxxxx12', 'xxxxxxxx87', 'xxxxxxxx87'),
           R2=c('my_title', 'xxxxxxxx47', 'titleA', 'my_title', 'xxxxxxxx11',
                'xxxxxxxx64', 'my_title_24', 'my_title_2', 'my_title_2'),
           R3=c('red', '', 'title_42', 'new_title', '', '', 'green', 'blue', '_title_'),
           R4=c('note', '', '', '', '', '', 'my_important_note', 'yet another note', ''))
```

Here is an extract of my audit log:

```
X_ID    EVENT   UNIT    CREATED     R1          R2          R3          R4
1       create  30xx    2015-12-01  xxxxxxxx11  my_title    red         'note'          
2       delete  30xx    2015-12-01  title       xxxxxxxx47
4       update  30xx    2015-12-02  xxxxxxxx25  titleA      title_42
5       update  30xx    2015-12-04  xxxxxxxx11  my_title    new_title           
6       delete  30xx    2015-12-05  new_title   xxxxxxxx11      
7       delete  30xx    2015-12-06  _title      xxxxxxxx64          
8       create  30xx    2015-12-10  xxxxxxxx12  my_title_24 green       'my_important_note'         
9       create  30xx    2015-12-10  xxxxxxxx87  my_title_2  blue        'yet another note'
10      update  30xx    2015-12-10  xxxxxxxx87  my_title_2  _title_
```

I want to structure this log by reassigning the r1 to r4 column to clearer column like this:

```
X_ID    EVENT   UNIT    CREATED     ELEMENT_ID  TITLE       NEW_TITLE   COLOR   COMMENT
1       create  30xx    2015-12-01  xxxxxxxx11  my_title                red     'note'          
2       delete  30xx    2015-12-01  xxxxxxxx47  title
4       update  30xx    2015-12-02  xxxxxxxx25  titleA      title_42
5       update  30xx    2015-12-04  xxxxxxxx11  my_title    new_title           
6       delete  30xx    2015-12-05  xxxxxxxx11  new_title       
7       delete  30xx    2015-12-06  xxxxxxxx64  _title          
8       create  30xx    2015-12-10  xxxxxxxx12  my_title_24             green   'my_important_note'         
9       create  30xx    2015-12-10  xxxxxxxx87  my_title_2              blue    'yet another note'
10      update  30xx    2015-12-10  xxxxxxxx87  my_title_2  _title_
```

Here is my approach in R where I try to apply a function with conditions to each rows:

```
struct_log <- apply(auditlog, 1, function(row) {
   if (row['EVENT'] == 'create') { row['ELEMNT_ID'] <- row['R1']; row['TITLE'] <- row['R2']; row['COLOR'] <- row['R3']; row['COMMENT'] <- row['R4'] }
   else if (row['EVENT'] == 'delete') { row['TITLE'] <- row['R1']; row['ELEMNT_ID'] <- row['R2'] }
   else if (row['EVENT'] == 'update') { row['ELEMENT_ID'] <- row['R1']; row['TITLE'] <- row['R2']; row['NEW_TITLE'] <- row['R3'] } }
})
```

Now I don't know why I'm not getting back a data frame.

Comment: In this case, I would read the part after 'CREATED' in the log file as a single column of logText or something and use regular expressions in R code to further split into other rows since there is no real structure to that text. Look at str_extract() from 'stringr' package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(OK, 2nd answer after the comment:)

I have modified your initial approach. First, you need to set **all** columns in the `if` statements (i.e. including the blank ones); second, you need to `return` the function result. Here is the whole code (including the modification in `auditlog` definition):

```
auditlog <- data.frame(X_ID=c(1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                   EVENT=c('create', 'delete', 'update', 'update', 'delete', 'delete', 'create', 
                           'create', 'update'),
                   UNIT=c('30xx', '30xx', '30xx', '30xx', '30xx', '30xx', '30xx', '30xx', '30xx'),
                   CREATED=c('2015-12-01', '2015-12-01', '2015-12-02', '2015-12-04',
                             '2015-12-05', '2015-12-06', '2015-12-10', '2015-12-10',
                             '2015-12-10'),
                   R1=c('xxxxxxxx11', 'title', 'xxxxxxxx25', 'xxxxxxxx11', 'new_title',
                        '_title', 'xxxxxxxx12', 'xxxxxxxx87', 'xxxxxxxx87'),
                   R2=c('my_title', 'xxxxxxxx47', 'titleA', 'my_title', 'xxxxxxxx11',
                        'xxxxxxxx64', 'my_title_24', 'my_title_2', 'my_title_2'),
                   R3=c('red', '', 'title_42', 'new_title', '', '', 'green', 'blue', '_title_'),
                   R4=c('note', '', '', '', '', '', 'my_important_note', 'yet another note', ''),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE  # added
                   )


ff <- function(row) {
  if (row['EVENT'] == 'create')      { row['ELEMENT_ID'] <- row['R1']; row['TITLE'] <- row['R2']; row['NEW_TITLE'] <- ''; row['COLOR'] <- row['R3']; row['COMMENT'] <- row['R4'] }
  else if (row['EVENT'] == 'delete') { row['ELEMENT_ID'] <- row['R2']; row['TITLE'] <- row['R1']; row['NEW_TITLE'] <- row['COLOR'] <- row['COMMENT'] <- '' }
  else if (row['EVENT'] == 'update') { row['ELEMENT_ID'] <- row['R1']; row['TITLE'] <- row['R2']; row['NEW_TITLE'] <- row['R3']; row['COLOR'] <- row['COMMENT'] <- '' } 
  return(row)  # added
}  

struct_log <- t(apply(auditlog,1,ff))
struct_log <- as.data.frame(struct_log)
new_names <- c("ELEMENT_ID", "TITLE", "NEW_TITLE", "COLOR", "COMMENT")
names(struct_log) <- c(names(auditlog), new_names)
struct_log[c('R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4')] <- list(NULL)  # drop 'R' columns
```

After which you again have:

```
    X_ID  EVENT UNIT    CREATED ELEMENT_ID       TITLE NEW_TITLE COLOR           COMMENT
1    1 create 30xx 2015-12-01 xxxxxxxx11    my_title             red              note
2    2 delete 30xx 2015-12-01 xxxxxxxx47       title                                  
3    4 update 30xx 2015-12-02 xxxxxxxx25      titleA  title_42                        
4    5 update 30xx 2015-12-04 xxxxxxxx11    my_title new_title                        
5    6 delete 30xx 2015-12-05 xxxxxxxx11   new_title                                  
6    7 delete 30xx 2015-12-06 xxxxxxxx64      _title                                  
7    8 create 30xx 2015-12-10 xxxxxxxx12 my_title_24           green my_important_note
8    9 create 30xx 2015-12-10 xxxxxxxx87  my_title_2            blue  yet another note
9   10 update 30xx 2015-12-10 xxxxxxxx87  my_title_2   _title_
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to do it with indices. Here is how, but first you should also include a `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` argument to your `auditlog` definition:

```
k <- nrow(auditlog)

# build an empty dataframe:
struct_log <- data.frame(X_ID=numeric(k),
                     EVENT=character(k),
                     UNIT=character(k),
                     CREATED=character(k),
                     ELEMENT_ID=character(k),
                     TITLE=character(k),
                     NEW_TITLE=character(k),
                     COLOR=character(k),
                     COMMENT=character(k),
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

struct_log[,1:4] <- auditlog[,1:4] # keep first 4 columns as-is

ind <- which(auditlog['EVENT']=='create')
struct_log[ind,'ELEMENT_ID'] <- auditlog[ind,'R1']
struct_log[ind,'TITLE'] <- auditlog[ind,'R2']
struct_log[ind,'COLOR'] <- auditlog[ind,'R3']
struct_log[ind,'COMMENT'] <- auditlog[ind,'R4']

ind <- which(auditlog['EVENT']=='delete')
struct_log[ind,'TITLE'] <- auditlog[ind,'R1']
struct_log[ind,'ELEMENT_ID'] <- auditlog[ind,'R2']

ind <- which(auditlog['EVENT']=='update')
struct_log[ind,'ELEMENT_ID'] <- auditlog[ind,'R1']
struct_log[ind,'TITLE'] <- auditlog[ind, 'R2']
struct_log[ind,'NEW_TITLE'] <- auditlog[ind,'R3']
```

Which results to what you want:

```
  X_ID  EVENT UNIT    CREATED ELEMENT_ID       TITLE NEW_TITLE COLOR           COMMENT
1    1 create 30xx 2015-12-01 xxxxxxxx11    my_title             red              note
2    2 delete 30xx 2015-12-01 xxxxxxxx47       title                                  
3    4 update 30xx 2015-12-02 xxxxxxxx25      titleA  title_42                        
4    5 update 30xx 2015-12-04 xxxxxxxx11    my_title new_title                        
5    6 delete 30xx 2015-12-05 xxxxxxxx11   new_title                                  
6    7 delete 30xx 2015-12-06 xxxxxxxx64      _title                                  
7    8 create 30xx 2015-12-10 xxxxxxxx12 my_title_24           green my_important_note
8    9 create 30xx 2015-12-10 xxxxxxxx87  my_title_2            blue  yet another note
9   10 update 30xx 2015-12-10 xxxxxxxx87  my_title_2   _title_
```

**Don't forget** to include the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to the `auditlog` definition (similarly to what I have done with `struct_log` above), otherwise it will not work...

Comment: Thanks @desertnaut. Is it possible to avoid creating an empty dataframe? I have more than 100 events and they evolves. I prefer to have one line for each event in my code with the rules regarding r's. Like if(EVENT == 'create') { R1 == "element_id" and R2 == "title" and ...). Your solution works perfectly but requires to much code updates when I add some events and/or change the r's rules